# Where should a factory for creating an Aggregate be placed?

Tags: domain-driven-design

We can place a factory on an *Aggregate root*, on an object closely involved in spawning another object or we can implement it as a *Service* ( which usually creates an *entire Aggregate* ).

a) In most situations, where should a factory for creating an *Aggregate root* be placed ( assuming it makes sense to create just the *root* and not the *entire Aggregate* )? On *the root* itself?

b) Similarly, where should in most situations a *factory* for creating a *complete Aggregate* be placed?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if this might help, but in Java I put them in the same package (.net namespace) as the class that it's trying to create, as the factories and services (in my view) are part of the domain model. Maybe some people prefer to put the factories in a different package, but I think it might be a matter of style. I always put these factories in separate classes, as their responsibility is very different than the responsibility of the object they are creating (build an object Vs pure domain logic).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that Factories belong to domain layer

Comment: I don't think there is a set of rules that apply to all situations. It really does depend on your domain and the type of expressiveness you want to achieve. You could create a constructor method on the aggregate itself, have an external class construct the aggregate for you, or look to services to do the job. In some instances you may want to guard against invariants, in other cases not. Important this is that the domain expresses the business intent.

Comment: @stephenl: I know it depends on a situation, but I was hoping for some general guidelines, similar to those Evans gave in his book with regards to non-root entities ( ex. place factory on the root when you want to add elements inside an Aggregate, place it in a closely related object when data and rules of related object are very dominant in the creation of an object etc <-- these guidelines aren't applicable in all situations, but they are still darn useful and give you a starting point, and now I'm looking for similar rules when it comes to roots )

Comment: @user437291: Where the creation logic of your Aggregates is rather complex, then you can use separate classes to do the job, but these are really second class citizens in your domain and have no other function than creating an object. This could be applied to both root and non-root entities. But generally speaking, placing a well designed Factory Method on specific Aggregate Roots allows you to enforce your invariants and creation logic of other Aggregates. Also allows you to make your Aggregates more expressive as the creation logic is contained within it.

Comment: @stephenl: So answer to both a) and b) is that root R1 itself should contain a factory that builds R1 and/or R1 aggregate?

Comment: @user437291: I would say yes, in most cases let the Aggregate be responsible for its own creation and use factory classes in more complex scenarios or where it makes sense to.

Answer (score 0):

> a) In most situations, where should a factory for creating an Aggregate root be placed ( assuming it makes sense to create just the root and not the entire Aggregate )? On the root itself?

When it makes sense to create just the Aggregate root object itself, offer a factory method.  To my ears, most of the time this is merely a static convenience method for allocating memory and calling an initialization routine (`[Foo fooWithBar:...]` instead of `[[Foo alloc] initWithBar:...]` in Objective-C) or using a constructor with parameters (`new Foo(...)` in Ruby, for example).

> b) Similarly, where should in most situations a factory for creating a complete Aggregate be placed?

Is testing an issue?

I found verifying static (factory) method behavior a pain to test.  Essentially, you'd have to treat your code like legacy code and refactor until it's testable.  If the tests dictate the code, though, you wouldn't run into problems like these.  Instead of using the *Factory Method Pattern*, you'd use an *Abstract Factory* instead and rely on its instance methods.

So, if you put the factory inside a designated factory object:  to create complex aggregate objects, I tend to use multiple factory objects.  There the one *Aggregate Root Factory* everyone else will talk to.  It utilizes factories for the components the aggregate is made of.  This way, you don't shovel complex object creations into one single factory which is prone to change often as your code base evolves.  Instead, the *Aggregate Root Factory* depends on other factories to do the initialization of the parts.

The factories should be placed in the domain layer, as commenters to your question already pointed out.

**Edit:** Especially when you reconstitute an aggregate from a repository will using multiple factories be useful.  If you put in a deeply nested JSON, for example, you can only test for the object returned by the factory.  If you delegate creating sub-objects to other factories, though, then you'll be able to (1) mock them in tests, and (2) verify that the *Aggregate Root Factory* (i) called its collaborators with (ii) the data split up already.